# URL 301 redirect via .htaccess file in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
www.example.com/products/223/category/sub_category/product_name.html

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$2/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The above redirect rule redirects me to below URL.

```
www.example.com/category/sub_category/product_name/p223
```

I want to update it so that it will redirect 
from

```
www.example.com/products/223/category/sub_category/product_name.html
```

to

```
www.example.com/product-name/p223
```

I want to show product name ("_" should replace "-") and product ID with prefix "P".

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^_]+)_([^.]+)\.html$ http://example.com/$4-$5/p$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

This redirects :

```
 www.example.com/products/223/category/sub_category/product_name.html
```

To

```
 www.example.com/product-name/p223
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention but the category and subcategory is also dynamic in the url.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                  RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/(.*)/(.*)/([^_]+)_([^.]+).html$  /$4-$5/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]                                This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The below redirect works for me.

```
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/(.*)/(.*)/([^_]+)_([^.]+).html$ /$4-$5/p$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```